# How to use re to find consecutive, repeated chars

Tags: python, regex

I want to find all consecutive, repeated character blocks in a string. For example, consider the following:

```
s = r'http://www.google.com/search=ooo-jjj'
```

What I want to find this: `www`, `ooo` and `jjj`.

I tried to do it like this:

```
m = re.search(r'(\w)\1\1', s)
```

But it doesn't seem to work as I expect. Any ideas?

Also, how can I do it in Bash?

Comment: Doesn't work how exactly?  It finds the first match.  If you want all matches at once, try `findall`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`((\w)\2{2,})` matches 3 or more consecutive characters:

```
In [71]: import re
In [72]: s = r'http://www.google.com/search=ooo-jjjj'
In [73]: re.findall(r'((\w)\2{2,})', s)
Out[73]: [('www', 'w'), ('ooo', 'o'), ('jjjj', 'j')]

In [78]: [match[0] for match in re.findall(r'((\w)\2{2,})', s)]
Out[78]: ['www', 'ooo', 'jjjj']
```

`(\w)` matches any alphanumeric character.

`((\w)\2)` matches any alphanumeric character followed by the same character, since `\2` matches the contents of group number 2. 
Since I nested the parentheses, group number 2 refers to the character matched by `\w`.

Then putting it all together, 
`((\w)\2{2,})` matches any alphanumeric character, followed by the same character repeated **2 or more additional times**.

In total, that means the regex require the character to be repeated 3 or more times.

Comment: @Alcott: `(\w){2,}` will match *any* 2 or more characters. It doesn't require that the characters be the same.

Comment: @Alcott: `(\w)` matchs any alphanumeric character. `((\w)\2)` matchs any alphanumeric character followed by the same character, since `\2` matches the contents of group number 2. Since I nested the parentheses, group number 2 refers to the character matched by `\w`. Then putting it all together,  `((\w)\2{2,})` matchs any alphanumeric character, followed by the same character repeated 2 or more additional times. In total, that means the regex require the character to be repeated 3 or more times.

Comment: Can I finish the job by `re.search(r'((\w)\2{2,})', s)`, which uses `search` not `findall`.

Answer (score 3):

The following code should solve your problem:

```
s="abc def aaa bbb ccc def hhh"

for match in re.finditer(r"(\w)\1\1", s):
    print s[match.start():match.end()]
```

Answer (score 0):

It works almost right, just replace `search` with `finditer`. It returns an iterator, not a match but...:

```
m = [(x.start(),x.end()) for x in re.finditer(r'(\w)\1\1', s)]
```