# Filter strings where there are n equal characters in a row

Tags: python, string, list, filter, char

Is there an option how to filter those strings from list of strings which contains for example 3 equal characters in a row? I created a method which can do that but I'm curious whether is there a more pythonic way or more efficient or more simple way to do that.

```
list_of_strings = []


def check_3_in_row(string):
    for ch in set(string):
        if ch*3 in string:
            return True
    return False

new_list = [x for x in list_of_strings if check_3_in_row(x)]
```

EDIT:
I've just found out one solution:

```
new_list = [x for x in set(keywords) if any(ch*3 in x for ch in x)]
```

But I'm not sure which way is faster - regexp or this.

Comment: Related: [use re to find consecutively repeated chars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147796/python-use-re-to-find-consecutively-repeated-chars)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Regular Expression, like this

```
>>> list_of_strings = ["aaa", "dasdas", "aaafff", "afff", "abbbc"]
>>> [x for x in list_of_strings if re.search(r'(.)\1{2}', x)]
['aaa', 'aaafff', 'afff', 'abbbc']
```

Here, `.` matches any character and it is captured in a group (`(.)`). And we check if the same captured character (we use the backreference `\1` refer the first captured group in the string) appears two more times (`{2}` means two times).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Nice solution. I've already found out one way - I've edited my post.

Comment: @Milan You can use `timeit` module to check. But RegEx version might be better than your `any` version.

Comment: My _guess_ is that the regex will be faster if the strings are long, since it only scans through each string once, whereas the `any()` approach scans an _n_ length string _n_ times. OTOH, if most strings in the list _do_ contain a group of 3, and that group tends to occur near the start of the string, then the `any()` approach _might_ be faster.