# Find "one letter that appears twice" in a string

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm trying to catch if one letter that appears twice in a string using RegEx (or maybe there's some better ways?), for example my string is:

```
ugknbfddgicrmopn
```

The output would be:

```
dd
```

However, I've tried something like:

```
re.findall('[a-z]{2}', 'ugknbfddgicrmopn')
```

but in this case, it returns:

```
['ug', 'kn', 'bf', 'dd', 'gi', 'cr', 'mo', 'pn']   # the except output is `['dd']`
```

---

I also have a way to get the expect output:

```
>>> l = []
>>> tmp = None
>>> for i in 'ugknbfddgicrmopn':
...     if tmp != i:
...         tmp = i
...         continue
...     l.append(i*2)
...     
... 
>>> l
['dd']
>>>
```

But that's too complex...

---

If it's `'abbbcppq'`, then only catch:

```
abbbcppq
 ^^  ^^
```

So the output is:

```
['bb', 'pp']
```

---

Then, if it's `'abbbbcppq'`, catch `bb` twice:

```
abbbbcppq
 ^^^^ ^^
```

So the output is:

```
['bb', 'bb', 'pp']
```

Comment: You can use backreference, [`([a-z])\1`](https://regex101.com/r/wT7cA9/1)

Comment: You seem to expect -- but don't mention -- contiguity, and you don't explain what'd you want as a result if `"ddd"` were present.

Comment: @kevin what if the letter appears more than two times>?

Comment: @Tushar what if he wants to find those which appears exactly two? like fetch `dd` from `fddf` not from `fdddf`

Comment: @KevinGuan you need to use findall for getting more than one occurances. `re.search('([a-z])\1', 'ugknbfddgicrmopn').group()`

Comment: @AvinashRaj That was a _guess_, Not familiar with Python :(

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Huh? Tested on Python 2.7 and Python 3.5, both raise `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`.

Comment: @KevinGuan what would be your expected output if the input is `abbbbcppq`

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Sure, catch `bb` twice, so it's `['bb', 'bb', 'pp']`.

Comment: Do you mean letter appears twice **together** or **anywhere in input**?

Comment: Well, **together** in this case.

Comment: Quite Similar [\[python\]: use re to find consecutively repeated chars](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7147796)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You need use capturing group based regex and define your regex as raw string.

```
>>> re.search(r'([a-z])\1', 'ugknbfddgicrmopn').group()
'dd'
>>> [i+i for i in re.findall(r'([a-z])\1', 'abbbbcppq')]
['bb', 'bb', 'pp']
```

or

```
>>> [i[0] for i in re.findall(r'(([a-z])\2)', 'abbbbcppq')]
['bb', 'bb', 'pp']
```

Note that , `re.findall` here should return the list of tuples with the characters which are matched by the first group as first element and the second group as second element.  For our case chars within first group would be enough so I mentioned `i[0]`.

Comment: Ohhhhh, after re-read the answer I understand how does it work now. So `([a-z])` catch the first letter, and `\1` repeat it. :)

Comment: @KevinGuan ya, exactly.. `()` called capturing group. So `([a-z])` captures the first letter and the following `\1` is a back-refernce to the first capturing group. So `\1` refers all the characters which are matched by the first group.

Answer (score 32):

As a Pythonic way You can use `zip` function within a list comprehension:

```
>>> s = 'abbbcppq'
>>>
>>> [i+j for i,j in zip(s,s[1:]) if i==j]
['bb', 'bb', 'pp']
```

If you are dealing with large string you can use `iter()` function to convert the string to an iterator and use `itertols.tee()` to create two independent iterator, then by calling the `next` function on second iterator consume the first item and use call the `zip` class (in Python 2.X use `itertools.izip()` which returns an iterator) with this iterators.

```
>>> from itertools import tee
>>> first = iter(s)
>>> second, first = tee(first)
>>> next(second)
'a'
>>> [i+j for i,j in zip(first,second) if i==j]
['bb', 'bb', 'pp']
```

## Benchmark with `RegEx` recipe:

```
# ZIP
~ $ python -m timeit --setup "s='abbbcppq'" "[i+j for i,j in zip(s,s[1:]) if i==j]"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.56 usec per loop

# REGEX
~ $ python -m timeit --setup "s='abbbcppq';import re" "[i[0] for i in re.findall(r'(([a-z])\2)', 'abbbbcppq')]"
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.21 usec per loop
```

---

After your last edit as mentioned in comment if you want to only match one pair of `b` in strings like `"abbbcppq"` you can use `finditer()` which returns an iterator of matched objects, and extract the result with `group()` method:

```
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> s = "abbbcppq"
>>> [item.group(0) for item in re.finditer(r'([a-z])\1',s,re.I)]
['bb', 'pp']
```

Note that `re.I` is the *IGNORECASE* flag which makes the RegEx match the uppercase letters too.

Comment: Well, then as my edit, I want `bb` from `abbbc`. Okay I know that this is a short version of mine another example and that example of mine's output isn't the expect of my edit...sorry about that...

Comment: @KevinGuan In that case you need a set comprehension.

Comment: Well, if use `set`, then it can't catch `bb` twice as I said in comments of my question.

Comment: Ah, yeah. This is good :). But however, I'd like use regex in this case. Good to know there's *another usage* of `zip()` :D

Comment: @KevinGuan Yes but using `regex` is not pythonic at all, checkout the bec=nchmark result.

Comment: @Kasramvd: Performance isn't everything, and is most likely irrelevant in this case. Regexps are a tool to solve a problem, and they solve this problem clearly and concisely.

Comment: @VincentSavard Yep performance is not everything, but when? Actually most important points about a code is performance (in terms of memory use and run time) and then readability ( coding style, amount of code and etc.) And as you can see clearly the first approach is really more optimum and readable than regex recipe. but about the second one which is not very complicated, the main point is that it's very optimized in terms of memory use which in dealing with large data sets would be pretty much better and usable.

Comment: Performance is important when you profiled your program and determined which parts were bottlenecks. There's absolutely no reason to be concerned about performance in this context. Thus, readability should be the main factor, and this is completely subjective in this case.

Comment: @VincentSavard Yes, and that's what the first part does.

Comment: You cannot make this claim as there is no context to determine if this is a bottleneck.

Comment: @VincentSavard I'm not talking about bottlenecks, I just suggested a pythoic way, that's all and at the rest of my answer just suggested another approaches for another situations, which might be useful for OP and future readers.

Comment: that. because there is no reason to use a regex here.

Comment: @njzk2: One pretty good reason is that this does not do what OP wants for the string `abbbc` (e.g. `['bb']` for the regexp vs `['bb', 'bb']` for this code).

Comment: @VincentSavard OP has added the lat part after my answer, and make I remove my regex approach which exactly did that job (before accepted answer).actually he edited the code multiple times. Any way I will add another approach with regex.

Comment: @VincentSavard Thanks for your attention, and reminding!

Answer (score 9):

Using back reference, it is very easy:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'([a-z])\1{1,}')
re.findall(p, u"ugknbfddgicrmopn")
#output: [u'd']
re.findall(p,"abbbcppq")
#output: ['b', 'p']
```

For more details, you can refer to a similar question in perl: [Regular expression to match any character being repeated more than 10 times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660694)

Comment: `\1{1,}` would be written as `\1+`

Answer (score 5):

It is pretty easy without regular expressions:

```
In [4]: [k for k, v in collections.Counter("abracadabra").items() if v==2]
Out[4]: ['b', 'r']
```

Comment: Hmm...doesn't work if the input was `abbbbcppq`. Maybe the problem because that `if v == 2` :)

Comment: Your question is somewhat ambiguous: are we looking for all letters that appear more than once or only those that appear exactly twice in the whole input? This answer is accurate for the latter, but for the former `[k for k, v in collections.Counter("abbbbcppq").items() if v>1]` will do.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can use the generator to achieve this

```
def adj(s):
    last_c = None
    for c in s:
        if c == last_c:
            yield c * 2
        last_c = c

s = 'ugknbfddgicrmopn'
v = [x for x in adj(s)]
print(v)
# output: ['dd']
```

Answer (score 3):

"or maybe there's some better ways"

Since regex is often misunderstood by the next developer to encounter your code (may even be you), 
And since simpler != shorter,

How about the following pseudo-code:

```
function findMultipleLetters(inputString) {        
    foreach (letter in inputString) {
        dictionaryOfLettersOccurrance[letter]++;
        if (dictionaryOfLettersOccurrance[letter] == 2) {
            multipleLetters.add(letter);
        }
    }
    return multipleLetters;
}
multipleLetters = findMultipleLetters("ugknbfddgicrmopn");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
A1 = "abcdededdssffffccfxx"

print A1[1]
for i in range(len(A1)-1):
    if A1[i+1] == A1[i]:
        if not A1[i+1] == A1[i-1]:
            print A1[i] *2
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When answering, also add explanation of the code.

Comment: In this case if I have `ffff`, then the output would be `['dd', 'ss', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff']`.

Comment: Actually...this still doesn't catch `'ff', 'ff'` as I said in comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> l = ['ug', 'kn', 'bf', 'dd', 'gi', 'cr', 'mo', 'pn']
>>> import re
>>> newList = [item for item in l if re.search(r"([a-z]{1})\1", item)]
>>> newList
['dd']
```

Comment: What is the use if you give a list of items? this will not work for other strings.

Comment: I have used `re.search` which works only for string.

Comment: Also, it works for other strings. Like if you add item 'zz' in list then it will give both 'dd' and 'zz'.

Comment: What i am saying is you provided a predefined list. So it will match from list and you have given all the list items of length 2. So your program is not flexible. Given a string it will not give the required output. I am just saying that the input is in the form of a `String` not `list`.