# Selecting repeated identical char

Tags: python, regex, pandas, string

I am trying to spot sentences having identical repeated characters in the same word, for instance:

```
Sentence 
    are they saddddd?
    I don't want to go
    heyyyyy
    12333
    00unit
    00wolf                        
    01man                         
    20595                         
    2091996                       
    03dumbdumb
```

In order to assign a value 1 or 0 if they contains repeated characters or not (expected output below):

```
Sentence                         Lab
    are they saddddd?             1 
    I don't want to go            0
    heyyyyy                       1
    12333                         1
    00unit                        0 
    00wolf                        0
    01man                         0
    20595                         0
    2091996                       0
    03dumbdumb                    0
```

I have tried as follows:

```
df.loc[(df['Sentence'].str.findall(r'([a-zA-Z])\1{3}').astype(bool)), 'Lab']=1
```

But it does not assign correctly the value 1 whether at least 3 identical characters are consecutive.

Can you please have a look at my code and tell me why it is not working?

Some values, like `00unit, 00wolf, 01man, 20595, 2091996, 03dumbdumb`, are wrongly selected from the code above, as including three identical consecutive characters, while they do not have them.

Comment: I'm assuming you want it to select words that have 3 or more consecutive identical characters (ignoring words like "tell" or "book"). Do do this, I think you need to change "\1{3}" to "\1{2}"

Comment: Also while we're at it, what's the point of "|(\d)+" here? Are some of your strings just numbers?

Comment: Thanks @Nathaniel. it may happen to have only numbers in the string. I have tried it, but it selects also this value:  01man which does not contain any consecutive identical character, or another example, 20595

Comment: Related:[How to use re to find consecutive, repeated chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147796/how-to-use-re-to-find-consecutive-repeated-chars),

Comment: Your example data should include strings that the operation fails with.

Comment: As commented by @NathanielD.Hoffman above, why `|(\d)+`? That captures all the digits.

Comment: @QuangHoang, even removing it, the code above selects sentences which do not contain at least three identical consecutive characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern is any word character followed by at least two more of that character.

```
s = ['    are they saddddd?',
     "    I don't want to go",
     '    heyyyyy',
     '    12333',
     '    00unit',
     '    00wolf', 
     '    01man',
     '    20595',   
     '    2091996',   
     '    03dumbdumb']

df = pd.DataFrame(s,columns=['Sentence'])

In [25]: pattern = r'((\w)\2{2,})'

In [26]: df.loc[(df['Sentence'].str.findall(pattern).astype(bool)), 'Lab']=1

In [27]: df
Out[27]: 
                 Sentence  Lab
0       are they saddddd?  1.0
1      I don't want to go  NaN
2                 heyyyyy  1.0
3                   12333  1.0
4                  00unit  NaN
5                  00wolf  NaN
6                   01man  NaN
7                   20595  NaN
8                 2091996  NaN
9              03dumbdumb  NaN
```

---

Or `pattern = r'(([a-zA-Z0-9])\2{2,})'` if you don't want to match an underscore.

---

```
pattern = r'(([a-zA-Z0-9])\2{2,})'
S = df.Sentence.str.findall(pattern)
df['Lab'] = S.astype(bool).astype(int)

In [13]: df
Out[13]: 
                 Sentence  Lab
0       are they saddddd?    1
1      I don't want to go    0
2                 heyyyyy    1
3                   12333    1
4                  00unit    0
5                  00wolf    0
6                   01man    0
7                   20595    0
8                 2091996    0
9              03dumbdumb    0
```

Comment: I think `\w` includes `_`

Comment: @QuangHoang - yes, I added the second pattern in case the underscore was undesireable.

Answer (score 0):

How about putting `\d` in the character list, and change `{3}` to `{2,}`:

```
df['Lab'] = df['Sentence'].str.findall(r'([a-zA-Z\d])\1{2,}').astype(bool).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
             Sentence  Lab
0   are they saddddd?    1
1  I don't want to go    0
2             heyyyyy    1
3               12333    1
4              00unit    0
5              00wolf    0
6               01man    0
7               20595    0
8             2091996    0
9          03dumbdumb    0
```