# Count how many double and triple characters appear in a list of strings

Tags: python, string

I have a long list of strings (the following is just a sample of the 117k list):

```
names = ['abc', 'aabc', 'aaabc', 'abbc', 'abxcc']
```

Is there an efficient way to count how many double characters (e.g `aa`) or triple characters (e.g `aaa`) appear in it? The only way I can come up with is having some loop as follows:

```
for letter in alphabet:
  for word in strings_list:
    for letter in word
      etc.
```

But since my list is quite large I was wondering if there's a more efficient way.

I should also mention that my list is in Chinese, hence I have about 6600 unique characters

The expected output:

```
number_of_doubles = value_1
number_of_triples = value_2
```

**Update:**

To clarify, a string like `aaa` should count as a triple rather than 2 doubles

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Just updated my question to show it!

Comment: Try coming up with any solution and show it. This question is just too broad and doesn't really show [any attempts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/4727702).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use re to find consecutive, repeated chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147796/how-to-use-re-to-find-consecutive-repeated-chars)

Comment: `zip(word[:-1],word[1:])` will iterate through consecutive pairs in an iterable. You should be able to compose your answer with that.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych How is this broad? It's just counting the number of doubles and triples... There's a unique solution to this. For this example, the number of doubles is 3 (second word, 4th word, 5th word), the number of triples is 1 (3rd word)

Comment: @MauriceMeyer I think it might work, I'm trying to use it now. I think the key might be to get all 2+ characters repeat, then 3+ repeats, and subtract the second from the first to get only the 2 repeats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a custom function that does cumulative counts and use this to get consecutive doubles, triples, etc:

```
def cumcount(word):
    counter = [1]
    for i, c in enumerate(word):
        if i == 0:
            continue
        if c == word[i-1]:
            counter[-1] += 1
        else:
            counter += [1]
    return counter

#for doubles
>>> {name: cumcount(name).count(2) for name in names}
{'abc': 0, 'aabc': 1, 'aaabc': 0, 'abbc': 1, 'abxcc': 1}

#for triples
>>> {name: cumcount(name).count(3) for name in names}
{'abc': 0, 'aabc': 0, 'aaabc': 1, 'abbc': 0, 'abxcc': 0}
```

Comment: Except that this is semi wrong, `aaabc` has a triple but it counts it as 2 doubles

Comment: Should it be included in the doubles count at all?

Comment: It shouldn't as it is a triple

Comment: So if you have `aaaa`, is that one triple or two triples?

Comment: That will not happened in this case. The longest repeating sequence of characters will be 3 (so you don't have to think about 4+ characters)

Comment: @Penguin - Changed the logic I was going with. This might be more scalable/useful.

Comment: Perfect! This looks awesome. Checked it on the longer list as well and it's fast. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression `([a-z])\1\1` will match three repetitions of any of the letters a-z and `([a-z])\1` will match two repetitions.

```
>>> re3 = re.compile(r"([a-z])\1\1")
>>> re2 = re.compile(r"([a-z])\1")
>>> names = ['abc', 'aabc', 'aaabc', 'abbc', 'abxcc']
>>> for n in names:
        print(n, len(re2.findall(n)), len(re3.findall(n)))

abc 0 0
aabc 1 0
aaabc 1 1
abbc 1 0
abxcc 1 0
```

Your question is not clear as to whether `aaa` counts as a 2-match. If it doesn't you may need to do some supplementary checking. That might be unnecessarily tricky to do in a regular expression so you might want to eliminate double-counting some other way.

Comment: I see your point. It should count as a triple, I'll clarify that in the question